# How to specify regex for an input of indefinte length?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get comfortable with RegEx, in general, and JavaScript RegExp in particular. This is meant for my learning and I am **aware that string functions exist** to solve the given problem.

In a string of indefinite length, I am trying to select the all characters that are found b/w a starting and ending character. For example:

**Input:**

> LINESTRING (-83.1732840000000000 40.0046110000000000,
>   -83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000)LINESTRING (-83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000, -83.1721910000000000
>   40.0049080000000000)LINESTRING (-83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000, -83.1721910000000000 40.0049080000000000)LINESTRING (-83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000, -83.1721910000000000 40.0049080000000000)

**Required Output:**

> (-83.1732840000000000 40.0046110000000000, -83.1733380000000000
>   40.0048360000000000) (-83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000, -83.1721910000000000 40.0049080000000000) (-83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000, -83.1721910000000000 40.0049080000000000) (-83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000, -83.1721910000000000
>   40.0049080000000000)

My limited knowledge of regex makes me believe that the following should work:

```
patNew = new RegExp("(\(.*\)(?=[LINESTRING]))", "g");
```

But it produces the following output:

> ["LINESTRING (-83.1732840000000000 40.0046110000000000,
>   -83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000)LINESTRING (-83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000, -83.1721910000000000
>   40.0049080000000000)LINESTRING (-83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000, -83.1721910000000000 40.0049080000000000)LINESTRIN", "LINESTRING (-83.1732840000000000 40.0046110000000000, -83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000)LINESTRING (-83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000, -83.1721910000000000 40.0049080000000000)LINESTRING (-83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000, -83.1721910000000000 40.0049080000000000)LINESTRIN", "LINESTRING (-83.1732840000000000 40.0046110000000000, -83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000)LINESTRING (-83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000, -83.1721910000000000 40.0049080000000000)LINESTRING (-83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000, -83.1721910000000000 40.0049080000000000)LINESTRIN"]

What am I missing? Please, help out with a little explaination. Also, I tried it on rubular.com and it comes close to the what I need. Here is the output on rubular.

> (-83.1732840000000000 40.0046110000000000, -83.1733380000000000
>   40.0048360000000000)LINESTRING (-83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000, -83.1721910000000000 40.0049080000000000)LINESTRING (-83.1733380000000000 40.0048360000000000, -83.1721910000000000 40.0049080000000000)

On rubular, the 2nd and 3rd instance of "LINESTRING" are present in the selection; Why?

I know that the last segment is not selected because for it, a closing brace is not followed by "LINESTRING". Is that the correct explaination?

How can I select the everything b/w () and leave out LINESTRING in a string of indefinite length? Also, how would I account for the final portion?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to post the code that actually **uses** the regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to escape the parenthesis in [regexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression) with backslashes, but also the backslashes in string literals if you create regexes from them:

```
var patNew = /(\(.*\)(?=[LINESTRING]))/g;
// or
var patNew = new RegExp("(\\(.*\\)(?=[LINESTRING]))", "g");
```

I strongly recommend the regex literal, it is more readable.

Btw, there's no reason to make a capturing group around the whole regex, and you surely don't want `[LINESTRING]` to be a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) but a literal string - you need to escape brackets as well. And you'll need to make the [repetition non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy), otherwise you're going to match from the first opening to the second-to-last closing parenthesis. Also, with that lookahead you won't get the last group - it is not followed by `LINESTRING` any more, so either allow [string ends (`$`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) as an alternative or just drop it.

```
var patNew = /\(.*?\)(?=LINESTRING|$)/g;
```

Still, for your actual problem matching `/\([^)]*\)/g` should be enough.

Comment: thank you very mush for the detailed explanation. Your solution works. I am marking your answer as correct because of through explanation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating your regex incorrectly:

```
patNew = new RegExp("(\\(.*\\)(?=[LINESTRING]))", "g");
```

You need to double-up on the backslashes.

Alternatively, use native regex syntax:

```
patNew = /(\(.*\)(?=[LINESTRING]))/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you requirement is really only everything between `(` and `)` this simple pattern should do it `/\(.*?\)/`

What does LINESTRING represent here? Is it relevant for the parsing at all?

Comment: perhaps \([^)]*\) would be better?

Comment: @hank: The LINESTRING is a marker for the type of geometry that follows. The input that I need to parse would have those markers. For some other purposes though, I need to leave the markers(LINESTRING) out and select stuff with the parenthesis.

Comment: @hank. Your solution works. Thank you very much. I am giving the correct answer to Bergi for the detail. Thanks once again.